# SQL SERVER MULTIPLE JOIN: avoid duplicate values

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables in my db:-

Customer:

```
 CId | CName | CLocation | CJoinDate
```

Payment:

```
TxnId | TxStatus | TxComment | TxAmount | CId | TxDate
```

Appointment:

```
AppId | AppCode | CId | ADate | AComment
```

When I do a Left join with two tables then the calculated results come right. But when I try to do join with 3 tables then the result calculated is wrong.

for eg:-

If I try this query then the total amount calculated is correct:

```
SELECT c.CName, sum(p.TxAmount) 
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Payment p ON c.CId = p.CId 
WHERE p.TxStatus = 1 
GROUP BY c.CName;
```

In the above query I am just joining two tables which gives me the correct result.

Now when I want to show all the records in one table so I had to join 3 tables. 
Below is the query I tried:

```
SELECT c.CName as Name, sum(p.TxAmount) as Payment, count(distinct a.ADate) as Total_Visit 
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Payment p ON c.CId = p.CId LEFT JOIN Appointment a ON c.CId = a.CId
WHERE p.TxStatus = 1 
GROUP BY c.CName;
```

The above query gives me wrong Payment amount for each customers. The reason for the wrong result is the Appointments table has more rows as compared to Payment table for each customer. So to show all the appointment entries, the payment amount gets duplicated coz of which the calculation gets wrong.

How can I fix the above scenario witht the above query.

Tks

EDIT: Actually theres 2-3 more tables which I have to join similiar to Appointment table along with a GROUP BY clause for each month.

EDIT1: Fixed it by multiple CTE. Thanks for your valuable pointers it was indeed helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple CTE expression if you are sure that your sum is calculated correctly by the first query

```
WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT c.CName, c.CID, sum(p.TxAmount) AS sumAmount
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Payment p ON c.CId = p.CId 
WHERE p.TxStatus = 1 
GROUP BY c.CName, c.CID 
)
SELECT cte.CName, cte.sumAmount, count(distinct a.ADate) as Total_Visit
FROM cte LEFT JOIN Appointment a ON c.CId = a.CId
GROUP BY c.CName, cte.sumAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a sub query:

```
SELECT 
c.CName as Name
, sum(p.TxAmount) as Payment
, Total_Visit = (SELECT count(distinct a.ADate) FROM Appointment a ON c.CId = a.CId)
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN Payment p ON c.CId = p.CId 
WHERE p.TxStatus = 1 
GROUP BY c.CName;
```

Comment: Actually I have multiple tables to join. The above stated query is just a small problem of big problem.  So I wanted to know if theres something we can do with JOINs to fix things up.

Comment: Ok, you can use a sub query for the other tables as well. Consider to write your query with the sub queries, and the CTE variant from Pawel. Then use the one that has the lowest execution plan cost?

Comment: Can we use CTE or sub query with GROUP BY clause too as I have show the total for each month for a given year.

Comment: Sure, you can group it by the date, but it depends a bit about how you want to arrange the rows and columns (Year by year, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate total_visit per CId and then join the subquery

```
SELECT 
  c.CName as Name
, sum(p.TxAmount) as Payment
, Total_Visit 
FROM Customer c 
LEFT JOIN Payment p ON c.CId = p.CId 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.CId, count(distinct a.ADate) Total_visit FROM Appointment a group by a.CId) as a on c.CId = a.CId 
WHERE p.TxStatus = 1 
GROUP BY c.CName;
```